# Extra characters in .doc file when opened with textpad

Tags: type-conversion, document, textpad

When I open a document in textpad, some extra null character is appended between every character.

Like my document is having following text
बॉम्बे testing for webmail.

When I am opening in text it is coming as 
I....M....I t.e.s.t.i.n.g. f.o.r. w.e.b.m.a.i.l.

Can Anybody help me on this ?

Comment: Which program are you using ? Word ? Openoffice ?

Answer (score 0):

This file is in UTF-16 or UCS-2 format. When opening it, you must specify in which encoding you want to open it. Your text editor does not recognize this encoding automatically.

If your text editor does not allow for setting encoding on opening file, try using Notepad++ or Textpad.

Comment: Hi ,

Thanks for suggestion. I have tried to open in  Notepad++ or Textpad and found same issue.


Regards,
Vikas Hirwani

Comment: In Notepad++, look at the menu `Encoding` and play around changing the encoding and if you like, converting the file into other encodings.